# reverse proxy that caches post requests

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, varnish

I understand that varnish caches "GET" and "HEAD" requests by default.

My backend servers fail when I do a get request that is too long, so I made them respond to POST instead of GET. This works great, but I need a reverse proxy which can be configured to cache POST responses just like GET.

Are there any reverse proxies that can cache these post requests?

Comment: I'm curious why the servers do not fail if you use POST in stead of GET ... If it's because of Varnish' timeout, you can bump the first_byte_timeout and between_bytes_timeout to something that exceed the expected processing time somewhat.  It's probably better than tinkering with caching POST requests.

Comment: Well it has been 10+ years, but the question got attention so I will just respond for reference. It was because I was sending large paragraphs to a text-to-speech engine and browsers at the time placed arbitrary limits to get requests. So I had to change from get to post. But that caused too much work on the backend because people were requesting the same text over and over again so I was looking for a cache solution and nginx worked fine. But apparently this was "bad design because it doesn't comply with REST" or whatever.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems nginx does cache POST requests if you specify it.

> ```
> proxy_cache_methods POST; # GET HEAD
> proxy_cache_key "$uri|$request_body";
> client_max_body_size 10k; # 413
> ```

Comment: Related: https://snippets.bentasker.co.uk/page-2003170906-Caching-POST-requests-in-NGinx-NGinx.html

Comment: Related: https://medium.com/programming-articles/caching-post-responses-with-nginx-1c0c064bb6b0

Answer (score 4):

Reverse proxies cache *responses*, not *requests*. In any case, [it's not realistic to cache a response to a POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626083/1068283). The HTTP specification really doesn't allow for it, since the very act of sending a POST request is supposed to invalidate any cache for that URL, and the response is non-cacheable by default. You are supposed to send a redirect as a response to the POST request if you want the response cached.

Comment: I wasn't looking for HTTP compliance, just trying to get my back-end servers working. Users won't know about the black magic that goes on inside.

Comment: Some web services such as SOAP use POST requests for everything.  It is reasonable to cache POST responses as long as you know what you're doing.

Comment: @KrisPeeling OK, then, add _poorly designed protocols notwithstanding_...